# How do I avoid Kotlin's WebView showing blank spaces?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

Long story short, I tried using Constraint, Linear and Relative Layouts to see if there was a problem, tweaked padding, margins, alignment and even centered gravity on the activity_main.xml, which already looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/visorweb"
    style="@android:style/Widget.WebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|fill|fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

None of this worked. My Main Activity looks pretty standard for a WebView too, but I will show it in case you want to see:

```
  package com.boliviachan.test9

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.visorweb)
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.boliviachan.org")
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                if (Uri.parse(url).host == "https://www.boliviachan.org") {
                    //Esencialmente todo lo que esté bajo el host "boliviachan.org" debería cargarse dentro de la app
                    return false
                }
                // En caso de que se abra un link externo, debe cargarse en el navegador de preferencia del usuario
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).apply {
                    startActivity(this)
                }
                return true
            }

        }
        fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
            // Chequea si hay historial de navegación previo y deja que el usuario vuelva hacia atrás
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack()
                return true
            }
            // Si no hay historial, simplemente usará cualquier función que tuviera el botón atrás por defecto
            // Como por ejemplo, cerrar la app
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
        }

    }
}
```

When I load the site on any mobile browser it works just fine, but in this WebView it has both left and right sides white, except when a popup appears and it actually fills both sides of the screen. What can I do?

Comment: Your problem is going to be in your html, not in the layout if you're seeing space inside the webview.

Comment: Try loading a different website like www.google.com and see if it still shows the blank spaces.

Comment: Use the LayoutInspector in Android Studio to see if the ``WebView`` is filling the space it should be. Then you'll know if it's a layout issue or something to do with the contents

Comment: @Amy I actually did that, and Google seems to fit the screen size just fine, so can it be just the HTML interacting weirdly with my code somehow? As I said, it the webpage I'm using looks just fine in Edge, Chrome, Opera and my default phone browser

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks for the tip, I just checked it now and WebView is fitting the screen properly, I will check the contents then or if there is something wrong about how WebView reads the webpage